# How can I share resources with threads in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a thread reading from a specific plc's memory and it works perfectly. Now what I want is to start another thread to test the behavior of the system (simulate the first thread) in case of a conectivity issue, and when everything is Ok, continue the first thread. But I think I'll have problems with that because these two threads will need to use the same port.

My first idea was to abort the first thread, start the second one and when the everything's OK again, abort this thread and 'restart' the first one.

I've read some other forums and people say that aborting or suspending a thread is the worst solution, and I've read about syncronization of threads but I dont really know if this is useful in this case because I've never used it.

My question is, what is the correct way to solve this kind of situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a shared resource that you need to coordinate thread access to.  There are a number of mechanisms in .NET available for that coordination.

There is a wonderful resource that provides both an introduction to thread concepts in .NET, and discusses advanced concepts in an approachable manner

http://www.albahari.com/threading/

In your case, have a look at the section on locking

> Exclusive locking is used to ensure that only one thread can enter particular sections of code at a time. The two main exclusive locking constructs are lock and Mutex. Of the two, the lock construct is faster and more convenient. Mutex, though, has a niche in that its lock can span applications in different processes on the computer.

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking

You can structure your two threads so that they must acquire a specific lock to work with the port.  Have your first thread release that lock before you start the second thread, then have the first thread wait to acquire that lock again (which the second thread will hold until done).