# Is it OK to include a DBContext as a parameter to ParameterizedThreadStart?

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I am a novice at threading.
It would be handy to pass an existing Entity Framework DBContext, as well as an instance of my logging class as a parameter to ParameterisedThreadStart , so that the new process can make use of them.

Could doing this cause race conditions?

Comment: should not if your threads have all the actions in the order they should be executed. However if you plan to split a transaction between two threads this could cause issues

Comment: Bear in mind that `DbContext` is not thread safe.(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_6)

Comment: So I guess I should create a separate DbContext within the procedure that is being started, rather than passing it as a parameter?
How do I find out whether my logging class is thread safe?

Comment: I note that I can use shared resources without passing them as a parameter . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611407/how-can-i-share-resources-with-threads-in-c.